td cell to appear directly below th cell
I have a table html like the following:


<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



I want the table to look something like this:
 Header1   Header2         
 td1       td2   
 Header3   Header4   Header5 
 td3       td4       td5

Can this be achieved using CSS without changing the html structure?

What's the reason you can't alter the HTML? Unsure why you are placing the th's and td's in the same row and expect the td's to be shown in a new row. Please clarify

I don't see an easy way to solve this. Can you give some more detail about if and why the HTML has to be structured like this?
If there's no way around having the HTML like this, I'd probably use Javascript to rearrange it.

This sounds like an X/Y problem. Please tell us the reason for the strange HTML and why you do not want to change it. It looks like it is a key-value set that has been rendered inappropriately.

There are other multiple solutions to achieve the desired output but you can't do this as you wished.

This is a html getting generated by a code using a template config. To change the html structure, I will need access to the code, which I do not have. However, the template also provides config for CSS. Hence why I want to achieve this with purely CSS.

You could lay the table out as a grid:


<style>
  table {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto);
    width: fit-content;
  }
  
  tbody,
  tr {
    display: contents;
  }
  
  tr:first-child th {
    grid-row: 1;
  }
  
  tr:first-child td {
    grid-row: 2;
  }
  
  tr:last-child th {
    grid-row: 3;
  }
  
  tr:last-child td {
    grid-row: 4;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 1</th>
      <td>Data 1</td>
      <th>Header 2</th>
      <td>Data 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Header 3</th>
      <td>Data 3</td>
      <th>Header 4</th>
      <td>Data 4</td>
      <th>Header 5</th>
      <td>Data 5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>



Note: I don't necessarily recommend this unless you are really stuck with that weird HTML structure and it absolutely can't be changed. The semantics are a mess with the given structure, the th should be in the first row as headings. However, if you are truly stuck with the structure then grid will lay things out the way you want.

Please follow table tags structure rules.
BUT if you insist to use Table tags.
Try table nesting
<table >
    <tbody>
       
        <tr>
            <td>
              <table>
                  <tr><th>Header 1</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>Data 1</td></tr>
              </table>
            </td> 
            <td>
              <table>
                  <tr><th>Header 2</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>Data 2</td></tr>
              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <table>
                  <tr><th>Header 3</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>Data 3</td></tr>
              </table>
            </td> 
            <td>
              <table>
                  <tr><th>Header 4</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>Data 4</td></tr>
              </table>
            </td>
            <td>
              <table>
                  <tr><th>Header 5</th></tr>
                  <tr><td>Data 5</td></tr>
              </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        
    </tbody>
</table>

OR use BR or styling the div for heading and data
 <table >
        <tbody>
           
            <tr>
                <td>
                      Header 1
                      <br>
                      Data 1
                </td> 
                <td>
                      Header 2
                      <br>
                      Data 2
                </td> 
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                      Header 3
                      <br>
                      Data 3
                </td> 
                <td>
                      Header 3
                      <br>
                      Data 3
                </td> 
                <td>
                      Header 3
                      <br>
                      Data 3
                </td> 
            </tr>
            
        </tbody>
    </table>


From OP: "Can this be achieved using CSS without changing the html structure?"

Yes used the first method. nesting by table will achieved the same result

You've still altered the HTML...

This solution might work, but is not tailored to the original question, stating that the  HTML shouldn't be altered
